# Updating GUI: Runnables vs Messages

Tags: android, user-interface, message, runnable

To update the GUI from other threads, there are basically two main approaches:

1. Use java.lang.Runnable with any of these methods:

   ```
   Activity.runOnUiThread(Runnable)
   View.post(Runnable)
   View.postDelayed(Runnable, long)
   Handler.post(Runnable)
   ```
2. Use android.os.Message:

   ```
   Handler.sendMessage(Message) / Handler.handleMessage(Message)
   ```

You can also use AsyncTask, but my question is more focused on the use case of updating a very simple component. Let's see how it would be done using both approaches:

1. Using Runnables:

   ```
   TextViev tv = ...;
   final String data = "hello";
   Runnable r = new Runnable() {

       @Override
       public void run(){
           tv.setText(data);
       }

   };
   //Now call Activity.runOnUiThread(r) or handler.post(r), ...
   ```
2. Using messages:

   ```
   Message m = handler.obtainMessage(UPDATE_TEXT_VIEW, "hello");
   handler.sendMessage(m);

   //Now on handler implementation:
       @Override
       public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
           if(msg.what == UPDATE_TEXT_VIEW){
               String s = (String) msg.obj;
               tv.setText(data);
           } ... //other IFs?
       }
   ```

IMHO, Messages are not the way to go because:

- Not easy to understand for new non-android programmers (handler hooks to its thread during construction).
- Object payload should be Parcellable if the message crosses process boundaries.
- Messages are reused (error prone if not properly cleaned up?)
- The handler has a dual role (it sends messages, but also handles them)
- Message attributes are public, but also offer getter/setter.

On the other hand, Runnables follow the well known command pattern, and are more programmer-friendly and readable.

So what are the advantages of using Messages over Runnables? Are Messages pushed into the background in modern day Android programming? Is there anything you can do with Messages that can't be done with Runnables?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Excellent question!

Answer (score 22):

I would say there is little difference between using a `Message` vs a `Runnable`. It'll mostly boil down to personal preference. Why? Looking at the source code you'll find that posting a `Runnable` uses the same exact messaging mechanism. It simply attaches the `Runnable` to a `Message` and sends that.

**4.4.2 Source Code**

```
public final boolean post(Runnable r) {
    return  sendMessageDelayed(getPostMessage(r), 0);
}

private static Message getPostMessage(Runnable r) {
    Message m = Message.obtain();
    m.callback = r;
    return m;
}
```

Ref: [Grep Code - Handler](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.2_r1/android/os/Handler.java#Handler.post%28java.lang.Runnable%29)

Comment: Hi can you confirm when we need to implement handleMessage method? I mean when we need child class of Handler? because we can direct communicate to Main UI thread by calling handler.post(); method.

Comment: Suggest posting that as a new question

Comment: Here I have created a new question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47336380/when-we-need-to-override-handlers-handlemessage-method

Answer (score 16):

`Messages` can be reused, so it results in fewer objects created and less GC. You also end up with fewer classes and anonymous types.

One big advantage is that a class sending a `Message` to a `Handler` doesn't need to know anything about the implementation of that `Message`. That can aid in encapsulation depending on where it's used.

Lastly consider the difference in cleanliness between

```
mHandler.obtainMessage(DO_STUFF, foo).sendToTarget();
```

vs

```
final Foo tempFoo = foo;
mHandler.post(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
        doStuff(tempFoo);
    }
};
```

If you have several places where you would have to `doStuff()`, the former is MUCH more readable and you'll have less code duplication.

Comment: Runnables can also be reused, it's also an interface and you could instantiate one in a cleaner way than the one you shown (which is also the one I posted :) ).

Comment: FWIW I think the key here is that Messages don't require the class building/sending them to know anything about the way the message will be handled. It's a way to expose to a client that you want them to send you certain information, but not what will be done with it. It's also handy if you want to be able to swap in different handlers at run time without messing with the code that generates the messages.

So in the case of the question posted, a simple UI update like this is pretty equivalent with a message or a runnable. But there are certainly cases where messages do offer added benefit.

Comment: The main reason imo why Messages would be useful is because the android OS actually queues them up, thats why at any point in time you can be sure that the messages sent later will only execute after the previous messages sent have been executed.

Answer (score 4):

`Handler` interface provides much more functionality than `runOnUiThread()`, according to docs:

> There are two main uses for a Handler:
>   (1) to schedule messages and runnables to be executed as some point in the future
>   (2) to enqueue an action to be performed on a different thread than your own.

`runOnUiThread` does only a subset of (2). ie "enqueue an action to be performed on ***UI thread***"

So IMO unless you need those extra features `runOnUiThread` is sufficient and preferred way.

Comment: Ok, maybe the idea is not clearly exposed in my question. It is not Handler vs Runnables, but Handler.sendMessage vs the Runnable alternatives. (This group includes also `Handler.postDelayed` and `Handler.postAtTime` which cover #1)

Comment: You actually explained the difference well in your post. I don't know any other difference I can add to those.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer `Runnable` to `Message`. I think code using `Runnable` is much clearer than `Message`, because the event handling code is very close to the event. Also, You can avoid the overhead of defining constants and switch cases.

And I don't think using `Runnable` violates encapsulation. You can extract the code in `Runnable.run()` into another method in the outer class, for example `on...Event()`, or even wrap it into an `EventHandler` object. Both ways are much clearer than using `Message`, especially when you need store references in `Message`, because using `Runnable` avoids downcasting `msg.obj`. And the nameless field `msg.obj` is also error prone and sometimes inefficient to understand.

And `Runnable` can also be reused by storing it as a field.