# When we need to override Handler's handleMessage() method

Tags: android, kotlin

I was learning about Looper and Handler and most time I read about it that it use to Communicate with UI thread. But then I saw the code which was child class of `Handler` with `handleMessage(msg : Message)` method then I got confused, because we can interact with GUI thread without extending Handler class.
As example in kotlin android.

```
val handler = Handler();
handler.post({ 
// update GUI here
});
```

So I can easily interact with GUI thread without implementing child class or `handleMessage()`.

Let me explain little more about my quesiton. Sometime I see this example.

```
class HandlerSub : Handler(){

    override fun handleMessage(msg : Message){
        // update GUI here.
    }
}
val handler = HandlerSub();
handler.send({ 
// send something..
});
```

So in the above example both code are being used for updating/interacting with GUI thread. but the 1st code is more simple easy and less code to interact with GUI.

Then what is real purpose of `handleMessage()` method and when we should implement it?

Comment: post is just a convenience method that delegates to sendMessage()

Comment: @Submersed I'm not asking difference between `sendMessage()` and `post()` I'm asking that when we need to implement `handleMessage()` method.

Comment: @Submersed I have updated my question, please read again.

Comment: Use sendMessage when you what obj.what to be some custom class and you want to cast to it based on the message id type.

Comment: @Submersed can you explain by an example in the answer?

Comment: @pskink why not post? I'm just want to confirm when should I implement `handleMessage` Can you give me an coding example in the answer?

Answer (score 1):

The sendMessage(...) call is used when you want message.obj to be some custom class, to send it to potentially another thread for processing.  This is normally done by having message.what be an ID, and knowing the object type for that particular id's message.obj, then casting to that object type.  This is used in many places throughout the Android framework, for example check the [BluetoothStateMachine](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Bluetooth/+/android-4.2.2_r1/src/com/android/bluetooth/hfp/HeadsetStateMachine.java) and how they handle `processMessage(Message msg)` in each one of their state classes.  Each one of these states is delegated to by Handler.

Comment: A simple code example will be helpful for me. I'm tied by reading theory... Sorry. -_-

Comment: Did you check how processMessage(Message msg) is implemented in BluetoothStateMachine?  Basically it's the same implementation as what could be on a custom Handler.handleMessage(msg: Message) implementation.  In Kotlin you'd probably just use when since it doesn't have switches.

Comment: Sorry there is no handleMessage that's why I'm unable to compare processMessage. -_-

Comment: handleMessage is in the Handler class...processMessage is in the State class.

Comment: Sorry I'm confusing more. I'm just asking how the handleMessage will be helpful for us? when we should Implement it? you say to determined some custom class and so on. But don't know what do you mean by this? when it could be require to provide custom class and so on?

Comment: @UnKnown [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/widget/Filter.java#215) or [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/content/AsyncQueryHandler.java#60) you will see real world examples of how to send and handle `Message`s - the `BluetoothStateMachine` is not a good example

Comment: ^^ Thanks.  Just knew that one off the top of my head, didn't wana go sifting.